# Objective-c: Multiplying an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a beginner's question about the fundamentals of objective programming (at least I think so..):

I have an UIView and would like to add several buttons to this UIView programatically. How many buttons there are depends on the user input.

Every button has four characteristics:

1. Its number (e.g. button number one, two, three etc.)
2. Its title (e.g. click this, click here, click me etc.)
3. Its position and size (i.e. a CGRect - size stays the same, only y-position needs to change)
4. Its colour (e.g. red, green, blue etc.)

Now I thought I can create a button by creating a method, but I am not entirely sure if this is a very sound method. I have the feeling that I should have created an object. Any help of how I should go about this would be very much appreciated. Here is my attempt - which is full of mistakes (for instance, I wasn't sure of how to create button1, button2 etc. -- hence the button[bNumber] thing):

```
 -(void) createIndexButtonWithNumber:(NSString *)bNumber withTitle:(NSString *)bTitle atPosition:(NSInteger *)bPosition withColour:(NSInteger *)bColour {

    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0,bPosition,25,25);
    UIButton* button[bNumber] = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame] autorelease];
    UIButton.text = bTitle;
    if (bColour == 1) {UIButton.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.751 green:0.742 blue:0.715 alpha:1.000];};
    [indexView addSubview:button[bNumber]];

    // to do: if button[bNumber] pressed {do something};

}
```

Then, I would like to 'multiply' the object three times by calling:

```
for (temp = 0; temp < 2; temp++) {
[self createIndexButtonWithNumber:temp withTitle:[@"Test%i", temp] atPosition:10 withColour:1];}
```

I'm sure this is all a bit problematic, wrong and clumsy, so I'd be very grateful for any suggestions of how to tackle this.

Comment: Excuse me, but aren't the buttons going to be exactly the same if you multiply them this way. If so, you could add them to an array so they get treated exactly the same. Sry if this is of topic :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to reference to [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

1. You should create buttons only with [`buttonWithType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType%3a) method.
2. Second, there is no button color. You can set a color for title with [`setTitleColor:forState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor%3aforState%3a) method.
3. There are just syntax mistakes in your code (`UIButton.text`, etc). You cant do such a call. `UIButton` is a class.
4. Your calling `createIndexButtonWithNumber...` within `for` will place buttons in the same place — `atPosition` input parameter has no change.
5. `NSInteger` variable is not a pointer — `*` is not needed.
6. ...

In the end of struggling we have smth like that:

`-(void)createIndexButtonWithNumber:(NSInteger)bNumber` //(sorry for that, some troubles with code formatting)

```
                          withTitle:(NSString *)bTitle 
                         atPosition:(NSInteger)bPosition 
                         withColour:(NSInteger)bColour {
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0,bPosition,25,25);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    button.frame = buttonFrame;
    button.tag = bNumber;
    [button setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %i", bNumber]  
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (bColour == 1) {
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.751 green:0.742 blue:0.715 alpha:1.000]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    };

    // you should pass to @selector a description like 'indexAction:' but NOT any calls like '[self indexAction:button]'
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(indexAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [indexView addSubview:button];
}
```

And `for` call:

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < 2; temp++) {
    [self createIndexButtonWithNumber:temp withTitle:[@"Test%i", temp] atPosition:30 * temp withColour:1];
}
```

**UPDATE: Selector method**

```
-(void)indexAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button with tag %d is pressed", ((UIButton *)sender).tag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Especially about the reference to the docs - I'm just reading that at the moment. But I have to say that I like your explanations a lot better. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a follow up question: I am trying to assign the same method to each button but would like to send a variable to that method. This is how my method looks like: `-(void)indexAction:(int *)buttonTag` and this is how I am trying to assign this method to each button: `action:@selector([self indexAction:k])` (with k being an int that I have assigned in the createIndexButton method... [self indexAction:k] doesn't work though.

Comment: please look through updates carefully. and read some obj-c/cocoa books! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example that I wrote that creates 5 buttons vertically in a row. The only thing extra in there is the tag, which is used to later reference the button if you need to.

I would suggest reading some more object orientated program examples as well.

```
float buttonPadding = 20;
float buttonWidth = 80;
float buttonHeight = 40;
for (int k=0;k<5;k++)
{
    UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.tag = 1000 + k;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, k*(buttonPadding+buttonHeight), buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %i", k+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much more sense than what I tried... Looking at examples is one thing -- applying them and putting into practice what you've seen is quite another. So thanks very much for your help.